# How can I get back my Entity from a Primitive and change its color?

Tags: cesium

I put an Entity (Rectangle) on the map:

```
var greenRectangle = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'The Area',
    rectangle : {
        coordinates : rectangleSelector,
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.2),
        heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
    }
});
```

Now I pick it from mouse move:

```
var handlerLatLon = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
handlerLatLon.setInputAction( function(movement) {
    var ray = viewer.camera.getPickRay(movement.endPosition);
    var position = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene);
    if (Cesium.defined(position)) {
        var pickedFeature = viewer.scene.pick( movement.endPosition );

        // the code to change Rectangle color

    }

}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE );
```

But `pickedFeature` is Primitive ( `Object { primitive: Object, id: Object }` ) and I have no idea how to change its color or take my Rectangle back.

I need to access the `Name` property too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Picking Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Picking.html) shows the official way to do this.  Click the `Pick Entity` button at the top.

The `id` field of the picked primitive, if populated, will be a reference to the Entity.

```
var pickedFeature = viewer.scene.pick( movement.endPosition );
if (Cesium.defined(pickedFeature)) {
    var picked Entity = pickedFeature.id;

    // Check if `id` is not undefined, and do something with it...
}
```

Using the `viewer.selectedEntity` method works too.  The selected entity changes based on picking code very similar to this.

Comment: The `ID` field? Not very intuitive huh?

Answer (score 0):

As usual I'm trying to make the things harder :/

There is a simple way to do this:

```
viewer.selectedEntityChanged.addEventListener(function(entity) {

    if ( Cesium.defined(entity) &&
            Cesium.defined(entity.rectangle) ) {
        console.log( entity.name );
        entity.rectangle.material = Cesium.Color.RED;
    } 

});
```

That's it!